# Jquery - Google Font Select with Font Size, Weight, Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to customize one of the functions I already have for selecting a Google font and updating the preview DIV, however I also want to add "Font Size", "Font Weight", "Letter Spacing" etc, but with this function it only works when you click on the Main Font Selecter combox box, I want it to check other options like font weight, size, letter spacing and then update the preview, I tried adding Jquery code indivudally for each element but them I cannot get the value ID of the main select box.. Can someone please help me make this, or atleast work on only one extra option that I have added, so that for the rest I will do myself.. Please take a look at this fiddle as I am almost 0 when it comes to jquery..

```
//init when value is changed
jQuery( '.google_font_select' ).change(function(){ 
    var mainID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    GoogleFontSelect( this, mainID );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3eWmJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these lines in your code:

```
var _selected = $(slctr).val();
...
$('.'+ _previewer ).css('font-family', _selected +', sans-serif' );
```

What we are essentially going to do is copy the code in order to change the other attributes of the text. What these lines of code do is define the HTML element that holds the options and change the value of the `font-family` CSS property. Basically, we just need to do the same thing, but for the other properties.

Using the [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) property as an example, let's assign a variable to the drop-down menu for font-weight:

```
var font_weight = $('#gfont_weight').val();
```

Then we use that variable to get the font weight and assign it like so:

```
$('.'+ _previewer ).css('font-weight', font_weight);
```

Comment: Thanks Dryden,  I have finally made all the changes I need.. thanks for your valuable input.. cheers